# IIS 8 sql server provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40

Tags: sql-server, iis-8

Today I'm trying to host my web site on IIS 8, this web site is developed in .Net MVC.
When I'm trying to do a query to SQL server, hosted in another server in my intranet, I have this error message: provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40, but if I host my web site on IISExpress(native in Visual Studio), or I do a query from SQL server managemet, all work fine. 
I use this string connection:

```
 Data Source=serversql;Initial Catalog=HD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*******
```

**serversql** is an alias that points to SQL server hosted in another machine. I have set up it in this way:
[cliconfg set up Image](http://img291.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=832668606_namedpipe_122_452lo.jpg)

Comment: show us your SQL connection string for IIS and for IISExpress.

Comment: Here is the connection string: Data Source=serversql;Initial Catalog=HD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*******

Comment: Where is your SQL Server? Is it on the same server as your IIS host? And can you access it with any other tools (VS, Management Studio, Excel, etc.)?

Comment: SQL Server is not on the same IIS's server, and I can access it with Management Studio.

Comment: Is the IIS Server and IIS Express server that you tested from on the same server?

Comment: Yes, I use the Visual studio's IIS Express, and IIS 8 installed in the same machine.

Comment: Well, I don't know why it would work then.  You can at least check the SQL Client configuration on the IIS box and the SQL Server configuration on the server box and make sure that they both have TCP/IP turned on (the "*Named Pipes*" bit is a red herring, NMP is just the last protocol it checks, but you want TCP/IP, not NMP).

Comment: I have edited the post (I haven't explained well), I don't use a TCP/IP but I use an alias (serversql) to link my web site to SQL Server.

Comment: OK, well, Microsoft doesn't recommended Named Pipes for SQL Server, but it does still support it.  So just do the same thing I said above (for Named Pipes instead of TCP/IP) and make sure that Named Pipes is turned on for the SQL configuration of both the client and the server.

Comment: Oops, one thing that I forgot: you should check this for both 32-bit and 64-bit on both the client and server as they are configured separately.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already set alias for 32 and 64-bit. What do you mean by "check the SQL Client configuration on the IIS box" ?

Comment: Its the same tool that you used to define the Client Alias, but one of the other tabs.  There is a 32bit and 64bit version of that as well.

Comment: I have done, but I have the same error message..I think that my PC is set in right way (IISExpress, and SQL server management, on my PC, work fine). In my opinion, the problem is IIS 8, or win 8, but I don't find out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to enable in the sqlserver's server the TCP connection, and on IIS's machine create an alias TCP to comunicate with server, I think that IIS 8 don't allows NamePipes.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the TCP/IP connection in Sql Server Configuration Manager program and allow the port in the firewall to be sure that's ok.

Name Pipes are available and can be enabled too but default value is false.
If set to true, named pipes are flushed when requests are terminated.